# How to generate an array in Python which shows the positions of the highest to the lowest integers or floats in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, integer

I'd like to generate an array which contains the positions of the highest integers/floating point numbers to the lowest in another array.
For example:

`integers = [1,6,8,5]`
I want the newly generated array to be:
`newArray = [2,1,3,0]`

or

`floatingPoints = [1.6,0.5,1.1]`
would become
`newArray = [0,2,1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `numpy` function `argsort` and then simply reverse the ordering as it gives you ascending rather than descending, by default:

```
np.argsort(integers)[::-1]
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
integers = np.array([1, 6, 8, 5])
np.argsort(integers)[::-1]
```

This results in the desired `[2, 1, 3, 0]`.